# Improvements suggested in closing changes URL

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

This question is for the Stack Exchange developers.

There are proposals made in the "here is what's changing/changed" section of  *[Closing changes: on hold, unclear, too broad, opinion-based, off-topic reasons, bye-bye to Too Localized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons)*.

Are these changes/improvements implemented using a engine (machine) or are the questions manually screened by a person?

Comment: _“Are these changes/improvements implemented using a engine (machine) or are the questions manually screened by a person?”_ Those are two completely separate questions. What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 1):

Moderators have the ability to edit the close reasons on each site. Changing them is a manual process—it always requires a human to type in the reasons. The system infrastructure handles the rest.

Changes aren’t retroactive (meaning, questions that have already been closed for that reason won’t have their close reasons changed); they only affect the menu of choices that is displayed from that point forward.

Although moderators can change the close reasons, we are advised to do so *very* cautiously, and only after discussion with the community.

So, any proposed changes should be discussed on Meta first (use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag), giving the community a chance to weigh in, whether that’s to say “no”, to suggest minor tweaks, or to give endorsement. “Consensus” is notoriously hard to judge on Meta, if achievable at all, so ultimately *someone* is going to have to make a judgment call. Generally, the moderator(s) will want to ensure that most of the other moderators and/or Community Managers (employees of Stack Exchange) agree with the changes.

In [the specific case you cite](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons), it wasn’t a moderator making changes in collaboration with the community, but instead an employee of Stack Exchange. Jaydles was a Vice President of Community at the time, giving him the authority to drive decisions like this. (Still, though, as the linked announcement suggests, this was discussed with the community.) However, [Jay has recently decided to pursue new opportunities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325178/goodbye-and-thank-you-jaydles).